# How to set decimal mark character or localization in CSVeed?

Tags: csv, decimal-point

new Problem: my employer wishes me to implement CSVeed utility for a project. It works just fine except that data formatting is not recognised correctly. The data to read is formatted with semicolon (;) as field separator and colon (,) as decimal mark. The information on the projects home page is telling me that decimal conversion is done automatically, but e.g. a string 0,5 in csv file is interpeted as 5, a string 9,5 read as 95. In the source code of the project i find Information: "Makes sure that a specific Locale is used to convert numbers.". I am not exactly sure where to tell the csveed lib which l10n to use. At another point of source doc it says utility will use l10n of framework. Is this from Eclipse RCP which i am using oder from the machine ? Sorry for not posting any code, but i didnt find barely a hint where to setup
the decimal mark in the utility...

Anyone an idea ?

Greetings :)

Answer (score 0):

My Goodness, why this verbose ? ^^

```
CsvClient<BeanClass> reader = new CsvClientImpl<BeanClass>(reader, BeanClass.class);

reader.setConverter("[name of property]", new CustomNumberConverter(Double.class, NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.[whereever]), false));
```

[name of property] has to be the name of the actual instance variable.

Greetings :)